# Keyset does not exist error for trusted publisher store

Tags: c#

I have installed a certificate in for local computer, Trusted publisher. When I right click on certificate in MMC – All tasks I don’t have option of manage private keys. Where usually I am supposed to give permission to "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool", to get rid of this error.
I need to get keys for this certificate, how do I do this?
When I installed same certificate for local computer – personal store I was able to right click – manage private keys and grant permission to "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool". So when I  look for certificate from this store I don’t get “ Keyset does not exist” error.

Thanks,

Comment: The solutions worked for me was always marked as accepted anwers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I just dragged a certificate from localMachine/Personal store ( which I had already asseigned permission to "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" ) to Trusted Publisher store.

Everything worked fine.